# GNSS planning online vs trimble planning 2.9 software

Tags: gps, planning

Why using the same parameters GNSS planning on-line and Planning 2.9 Trimble show me different Dilution of precision (DOP on the graph)?! Which program is better mission planning solution for GNSS measurement?

[Link to full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFFcs.png).

[image: GNSS Planning Online vs Trimble Planning]

Comment: I agree . Only that outcome be considered correct?

Comment: Unlikely that this would be causing your issue, but your time zones differ by 1 hour. Perhaps verify that the results are still disperate after making sure they are both up-to-date.

Comment: Also, do you have the latest almanac data?

Answer (score 1):

Although both applications are developed by Trimble, the online one is more up-to-date than the desktop one.  More specifically, the desktop version uses the so-called almanacs to predict the satellite position (thus their viewing direction in the sky), so please make sure you have the [latest ones](ftp://ftp.trimble.com/pub/eph/almanac.alm) installed.

Secondly, please make sure the settings are the same across the two applications, specially with respect to the GNSS constellations selected (GPS only or also GLONASS, GALILEO, etc.).  Not to mention the receiver position and epoch.